# Deviation between Mean and Median

Tags: mean, terminology, median

If I have a mean of 15 and median of 10, is there a term for the difference between these?

Can you use this difference of 5 for anything valuable statistically?

Comment: Tell us also the standard deviation and the interquartile range (IQR).

Answer (score 18):

The ratio (mean $-$ median) / SD has often been used as a measure of skewness. It has the perhaps surprising feature that it is bounded by $-1$ and $1$. But I would never recommend using it by itself -- without checking other measures of skewness -- or without looking at some graphs of a distribution.

In your case, and generally, it is also important to know whether your variable is always positive or always zero or positive.

Section 7 of [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X211063415) carries a miniature review of skewness measures.

I don't recollect (mean $-$ median) ever being given a specific name. It doesn't need one.

Comment: So $5$ is a lower bound on the standard deviation here.  Incidentally, if you have a continuous unimodal distribution then (mean − median) / SD [is bounded by](http://www.se16.info/hgb/cheb2.htm#3unimodalinequalities) $\pm \sqrt{\frac35}$ which would lead to a lower bound on the standard deviation here of $6.45$

Comment: This is in Wikipedia as https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_skew

Comment: [Pearson's second skewness coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson's_second_skewness_coefficient_(median_skewness)) is a multiple of 3 of this nonparametric skew.

Comment: Please see the linked paper and its references for much more detail.